# Disable button after hours of use during the day

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I have an app that I want to disable the button after 8 hours of use per day, being able to use it as many times as I want within 8 hours of the day.

Below is part of the button code:

```
children: [
                if (onMenuButtonPressed != null)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: CupertinoButton(
                      onPressed: onMenuButtonPressed,
                      //onPressed: (DateTime.now().second >= 1 && DateTime.now().second <= 12) ? null : () => onMenuButtonPressed,
                      minSize: 0,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Ionicons.menu,
                        color: ColorPalette.neutral50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I tried to include the code below, but it didn't work and it was commented out:

```
onPressed: (DateTime.now().second >= 1 && DateTime.now().second <= 12) ? null : () => onMenuButtonPressed,
```

Comment: So do you start the timer on the first button push? then track the time elapsed?

Answer (score 1):

Try your code this way,

```
DateTime? buttonPressedTime;

void handleMenuButtonPressed() {
  if (buttonPressedTime == null || buttonPressedTime!.day != DateTime.now().day) {
    buttonPressedTime = DateTime.now();
  }

  if (DateTime.now().difference(buttonPressedTime!) >= Duration(hours: 8)) {
    // Disable the button
    return;
  }


}

// Usage of the button
children: [
  if (onMenuButtonPressed != null)
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: CupertinoButton(
        onPressed: handleMenuButtonPressed,
        minSize: 0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: const Icon(
          Ionicons.menu,
          color: ColorPalette.neutral50,
        ),
      ),
    ),
],
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when you return the button to the counter it stops. How should I change it so that after the time expires, the button can only be used on the next day?

Comment: Now, try my changeable code to see if it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work. What is your contact? Do you have Telegram? Thanks.